# Unicode Strings in Text file

Tags: unicode

I have a text file containing the following unicode strings with regular text.

Cat a.txt

```
{"relationship":{"type:Memberkey","id""824-\u0001\u0019BFGHDICA2166-01-01","source"}
```

Here `\u0001` and `\u0019` are unicode strings and is causing our program to fail .

Is there a generic command to replace any such string?

Comment: Provide an example of replacement text, please.

Comment: current text - {"relationship":{"type:Memberkey","id""824-\u0001\u0019BFGHDICA2166-01-01","source"}                                                                    Replace text -{"relationship":{"type:Memberkey","id""824-BFGHDICA2166-01-01","source"}                                                                                                                          Need a generic command to remove the \u000* unicode string

Comment: Your input appears to be JSON, but it is not *well formed*. If you can provide a well formed [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) then you may get a better answer—possibly including JSON pre-processing with a robust JSON tool that supports Unicode (as per-spec). Also, the Unicode output "\u0001" may depend on your `cat`, locale and terminal; or may be the literal file contents, `hexdump -C` on the input is one way to check that.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it depends what you mean by "generic command" and what you mean by "replace."

I take you to mean that you wish to reduce Unicode to the most-similar UTF-8, in which case you want to look at [iconv.](https://linux.die.net/man/1/iconv)

You may find [this guide](https://www.tecmint.com/convert-files-to-utf-8-encoding-in-linux/) helpful.

You might instead be wanting to replace such strings with some arbitrary text of your own, in which case you want to look at [regex.](https://linux.die.net/man/3/regex)
You may find [this guide](https://likegeeks.com/regex-tutorial-linux/) helpful.

**Edit:** If you aren't quite sure what you want, then you likely should start by playing around with (a copy of) the file itself.  Once thing you should know (if you don't already) is the [printf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) command.  You may find [this guide](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/uprintf.htm) helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get rid of those control characters, you can use sed:

```
sed -i 's/\\u001[[:xdigit:]]//;s/\\u000[0-9bBcCeEFF]//' your_file
```

I assume you want to keep the CR and LF characters, even if they are encoded as `\u000a` and `\u000d`.